# ArrayList null object reference Android

Tags: android, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

I get this error:

> 04-30 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(13605):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.ribicinc.vzemialipusti/com.ribicinc.vzemialipusti.Skatle}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

What am I doing wrong?

My code, first activity:

```
List<Integer> skatlice = Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    ...

    if (cases[position] == 1) {
       myIntent2 = new Intent(Game.this, Skatle.class); 
       vrednostskatel = 1;
       myIntent2.putExtra("vrednostskatel", vrednostskatel);

       skatlice.set(0, 1);
       myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", (ArrayList<Integer>) skatlice);

       startActivity(myIntent2); 
       overridePendingTransition(R.layout.mainfadein, R.layout.splashfadeout);
}
```

Second activity:

```
 public class Skatle extends Activity {

        int[] skatle = new int[28];

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_skatle);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int cases = mIntent.getIntExtra("vrednostskatel", 0);
        List<Integer> skatlice = mIntent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice");
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");

        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            int amount = skatlice.get(i);
            skatle[i] = amount;
        }


        if (cases == 1 || skatle[0] == 1) {
                TextView layout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.izbrano);
                layout.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d7a308"));       
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageOdprto);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.o1);
                String strIi = formatter.format(cases);
                text.setText(strIi + "€");

                }
```

This crash occurs on the second Activity.

Comment: Check if your `skatlice` list isn't `null` before looping.

Comment: @Rami Skatlice is null, don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Try with `myIntent2.putExtra("skatlice", skatlice);` in your first activity and `List<Integer> skatlice = (List<Integer>) mIntent.getSerializableExtra("skatlice");` in the second one.

Comment: I get `The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Integer>)` at `myIntent2.putExtra("skatlice", skatlice);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just *cast* base class into child class. The object does not have info of ArrayList on line:

```
myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", (ArrayList<Integer>) skatlice);
```

Instead, use this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> skatlice = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) ;
```

and

```
myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", skatlice);
```

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: skatlice is null, I don't know how to fix that.